# How to add bootstrap scripts to django admin template?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-templates, django-admin

I want to use some **Boostrap** elements into the **django admin** interface.
For that purpose, I have overided the *admin/base.html* template. I want to add the links to bootstrap javascripts (the two lines of code you have to put just before the `` in order to use bootstrap) into that template.
As it is out of any `{% block %}` in the original *admin/base.html*, is there a nice way to do that without copying the entire  section ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

in your `admin/base.html` file add bootstrap style and js scripts using CDN as below;

```
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I hope this will help you as it works for me. Please try and if you have any queries related to this please add a comment.

[Getting started with Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer Akash. And soory for the delay on my comment.
I already know the elements you bring here. My only problem is : to add the <script> part, it has to be done just before the </body> tag. Which is out of any block in the admin/base.html. And so I have to copy the whole <body> in my own template. I find that not very 'elegant'. I was wondering if there was a better solution.